# how can I use iftop to listen to multiple interfaces

Tags: linux-networking

I have lo, eth0 and eth1 on my server and I want to monitor bandwidth on both eth0 and eth1.

I tried `iftop -nt -i eth0 -i eth1` but it only listens to eth1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont' think it is possible currently, iftop listens to network traffic on a `named interface`, or on the `first interface` it can find which looks like an `external interface` if `none` is specified, and displays a table of current bandwidth usage by pairs of hosts. iftop must be run with sufficient permissions to monitor all network traffic on the interface.

You have to run two commands for two interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Only way you can try that is probably by using the bridge interface but it won't be helpful as much because it still lists as one interface. 
You might want to consider using iptraf command.

Comment: Hello @Vasundhar and welcome on ServerFault! You probably sent your answer by mistake before completing it. Please take a read at [this](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and improve your answer since as is it will probably be deleted soon.